# cancel visa on damage passport

Tags: canada

I received the damage passport with Canada visa, next day I went to Canada embassy to inform about this and to confirm about next procedure. Even they not call me inside the office, nor ask any question just guard take my passport and gone inside after some time he came with cancel visa. I was surprised to see this. On stayed they mention cancelled without prejudice.

Edited in from a comment:
I want to know what should I do next. Can I apply again with new passport. As they cancel the visa without prejudice it negative sign to apply. Or will not effect this on reapplying.

Comment: Please fix your question to be understood. Include everything you are adding in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Get a new, undamaged passport and apply again at the Canadian embassy.
There should be no problem in getting the visa, due to the fact that it was only cancelled as the passport was damaged.

Cancellation without prejudice means that they cancelled the visa for no fault of yours and without resulting problems for you. So getting a new passport and getting a new visa should not be a problem.

If you think the Canadian embassy had something to do with the damage of your passport, you can send them an e-mail and ask for compensation. But it is more likely that the postal service they used made the damage, so going after compensation there first makes sense.

When you apply for your new passport, ask for your old passport to be returned to you, so you can show the visa as well as the damage if/when claiming compensation.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable advice I will apply with my new passport.i not need any compensation.but I was surprised they nt ask me any question or nt even allow me to come in the office.without know anything they cancelled the visa the thing was surprised me

Comment: I want to know what should I do next. Can I apply again with new passport. As they cancel the visa without prejudice it negative sign to apply. Or will not effect this on reapplying.